# I want to convert list of json files to csv with only specific attributes

Tags: json, csv

I have 1000 odd json files. I want to convert them into single csv file. I want only specific attributes in the csv file.

Here is sample json file

```
{
  "id": "90",
  "productName": "XYZ",
  "businessUnit": "",
  "daemon": "MSU",

  "features": [
    {
      "name": "MNQ",
      "count": "10",
      "id": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "PQR",
      "count": "20",
      "id": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the sample output

```
ProductName,FeatureName, FeatureCount
XYZ,MNQ,10
XYZ,PQR,20
```

I want to extract following attributes "productName": "XYZ " and from "features" array. I want to extract "name" and "count" attributes to a CSV file.

I want to this to 1000 odd JSON files and write it to CSV file. How to do this?

Comment: Give sample output too please

Comment: Hi  tetralobita, I have updated my question with sample output

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion, how to do this ,  I familiar with javascript and node.js

Answer (score 3):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --j2c cut -r -f "(pro|name|count)" then reshape -r "feature" -o k,v then nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs ":" -f k then reshape -s k_3,v then cut -x -r -f "_" input.json >output.csv
```

you have

```
+-------------+------+-------+
| productName | name | count |
+-------------+------+-------+
| XYZ         | MNQ  | 10    |
| XYZ         | PQR  | 20    |
+-------------+------+-------+
```

It's a commandline utility you can use in nearby every OS. Then you can do a simply for loop and merge all.